# How do I become a Hero in die2nite?

Tags: die2nite

For all the help text and upsell messages in die2nite, I cannot figure out how users are selected for Hero status. At first I thought the game had a "freemium" model where you could pay to be a hero but none of the "become a hero" links take me anywhere.

Are successful users from past towns granted hero status? Or is there a purchase flow that just isn't available yet?

Comment: It's free to be a hero now. Good chance to join.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may now purchase days of Hero time on the Die2Nite website.

There's also another way to become a hero: manage to pull out of a town that has lasted for five complete days as the Last Man Standing, and you'll be rewarded not only with a special distinction but also with a certain amount of Hero days depending on how long you survived. You can read up on Last Man Standing and the rewards [here](http://www.die2nite.com/#help/last_man_standing?sk=e655a).

Comment: Dammit @Mana, your answers are always so much more complete and detailed than mine would have been if I had answered first...

Comment: And by "pull out" of your town I mean die in a blaze of sleeping glory.

Comment: @Gnomes That's why they pay me the big bucks, bro.

Answer (score 3):

Now that the game is out of beta, you may buy hero time for roughly 12-15$ a month.